# How to deploy asp.net mvc 3 application to remote server msbuild command?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, msbuild

I am using

```
msbuild D:\SVN\QM\QMsln\QM.sln     /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Prof.pubxml
```

where publish prof Prof.pubxml deploys the web app in  my local machine.
It works fine. But now I want to deploy it on remote server. I created a ftp server in my remote machine. And while I tried publishing using VS2012. It throws an error

```
FTP Passive mode is not available
```

I googled the issue and inserted

```
<FtpPassiveMode>True</FtpPassiveMode>
```

in the Prof.pubxml. But still the problem persists.
Also If I use msbuild it says

```
This specific web publishing is not yet supported on msbuild command line.
```

Any idea?